# Astronauts exploring planet, classic sci fi

Tags: story-identification

I have been looking for titles of films I saw when I was young. This one particular film, from what I can remember had astronauts on a planet doing some exploring and came across what looked like a circular tower that had holes on  the sides of it with a ramp spiraling upwards. As they made their way up,what I think was black slime or oil came out of the holes and hampered their progress up. Any ideas?

Comment: when were you young? 1950 or 1999? What language was the film? Black and white or color? Country of origin / viewing?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a bit of a long shot, since I don't know if you would have watched German movies, but this might be "Der schweigende Stern"  (English "[First Spaceship on Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Spaceship_on_Venus)"), a 1960 coproduction between GDR and Poland after Stanislav Lem's "The Astronauts".

[This Youtube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UD5HPUddI2Y) has the spiralling towers with holes at about 2:25, and astronauts wading through oily stuff.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much Eike!!